# Save very large strings in Realtime Database - Best Practice?

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I´m using Angular with the Firebase Realtime Database and I need to store some very large data. A value has to be for example:

`key: ""\"\\n      // Meta-Box Generator\\n      // How to use: $meta_value = get_post_meta( $post_id, $field_id, true );\\n      // Example: get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), \\\"my_metabox_field\\\", true );\\n\\n      class MeinecooleMetaboxMetabox {\\n\\n        private $screens = array('qwdq');\\n\\n        private $fields = array(\\n          array(\\n            'label' => 'Your Label',\\n            'id' => 'text_yourlabel',\\n            'type' => 'text',\\n           )  \\n        );\\n\\n        public function __construct() {\\n          add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', array( $this, 'add_meta_boxes' ) );\\n          add_action( 'save_post', array( $this, 'save_fields' ) );\\n        }\\n\\n        public function add_meta_boxes() {\\n          foreach ( $this->screens as $s ) {\\n            add_meta_box(\\n              'MeinecooleMetabox',\\n              __( 'Meine coole Metabox', 'textdomain' ),\\n              array( $this, 'meta_box_callback' ),\\n              $s,\\n              'normal',\\n              'default'\\n            );\\n          }\\n        }\\n\\n        public function meta_box_callback( $post ) {\\n          wp_nonce_field( 'MeinecooleMetabox_data', 'MeinecooleMetabox_nonce' ); \\n          $this->field_generator( $post );\\n        }\\n\\n        public function field_generator( $post ) {\\n          $output = '';\\n          foreach ( $this->fields as $field ) {\\n            $label = '<label for=\\\"' . $field['id'] . '\\\">' . $field['label'] . '</label>';\\n            $meta_value = get_post_meta( $post->ID, $field['id'], true );\\n            if ( empty( $meta_value ) ) {\\n              if ( isset( $field['default'] ) ) {\\n                $meta_value = $field['default'];\\n              }\\n            }\\n            switch ( $field['type'] ) {\\n              default:\\n                $input = sprintf(\\n                '<input %s id=\\\"%s\\\" name=\\\"%s\\\" type=\\\"%s\\\" value=\\\"%s\\\">',\\n                $field['type'] !== 'color' ? 'style=\\\"width: 100%\\\"' : '',\\n                $field['id'],\\n                $field['id'],\\n                $field['type'],\\n                $meta_value\\n              );\\n            }\\n            $output .= $this->format_rows( $label, $input );\\n          }\\n          echo '<table class=\\\"form-table\\\"><tbody>' . $output . '</tbody></table>';\\n        }\\n\\n        public function format_rows( $label, $input ) {\\n          return '<div style=\\\"margin-top: 10px;\\\"><strong>'.$label.'</strong></div><div>'.$input.'</div>';\\n        }\\n\\n        \\n\\n        public function save_fields( $post_id ) {\\n          if ( !isset( $_POST['MeinecooleMetabox_nonce'] ) ) {\\n            return $post_id;\\n          }\\n          $nonce = $_POST['MeinecooleMetabox_nonce'];\\n          if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $nonce, 'MeinecooleMetabox_data' ) ) {\\n            return $post_id;\\n          }\\n          if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) {\\n            return $post_id;\\n          }\\n          foreach ( $this->fields as $field ) {\\n            if ( isset( $_POST[ $field['id'] ] ) ) {\\n              switch ( $field['type'] ) {\\n                case 'email':\\n                  $_POST[ $field['id'] ] = sanitize_email( $_POST[ $field['id'] ] );\\n                  break;\\n                case 'text':\\n                  $_POST[ $field['id'] ] = sanitize_text_field( $_POST[ $field['id'] ] );\\n                  break;\\n              }\\n              update_post_meta( $post_id, $field['id'], $_POST[ $field['id'] ] );\\n            } else if ( $field['type'] === 'checkbox' ) {\\n              update_post_meta( $post_id, $field['id'], '0' );\\n            }\\n          }\\n        }\\n\\n      }\\n\\n      if (class_exists('MeinecooleMetaboxMetabox')) {\\n        new MeinecooleMetaboxMetabox;\\n      };\\n\\n      \""`

This is just one example. There are some bigger strings I have to save in the database.

Is there a best practice to prevent to save large data like this? (Also pricing reasons. I think that large data makes it very expensive) Or would be not so dramatic? Pass them as query string not working. I get a 400 error.

What do you think about this?

Answer (score 1):

What you're showing here is not really very large.  Realtime Database can handle that just fine.

If you have large data, on the order of hundreds of kilobytes or above, it might be worthwhile to store that in a blob storage product, such as Cloud Storage for Firebase, and store a reference to that in the database.  It's entirely up to you, your needs, and your preferences.  There is no right or wrong way to do it.  If you have performance or cost concerns, I suggest benchmarking and doing some calcuations for cost, using what you see on the [pricing page](https://firebase.google.com/pricing).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I updated my question above and entered the largest data possible. Would also this not be too large to save in the database? What do you think?

Comment: It's still not that large.  You might want to read up on the database limits in the documentation.  The max size of a string is 10 MB, which is huge compared to what you have now. https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/limits#data_tree